# Group ManyToMany in Django admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have a model "Company" having many to many relationships with Country and City while country and city have one to many relationship between them.
The problem is that when loading an "enterprise" have to select the countries atienede the company and the cities they serve, but the list of cities is very long and also the cities are all mixed without distinguishing what country you are. What I'd like is to group the cities by country.

It is exactly what django-smart-selects, only this plugin does not work in many to many relationships. Someone could help me adapt this plugin to work with many to many relationship or comment me if they think of another alternative.

Thank you very much!

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    countries = models.ManyToManyField(Country)
    cities = models.ManyToManyField(City)

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution how you can solve this in the admin with smart_selects:

Define the through model for your manytomany relationship (company to city). In the through model you define the relationship to the city as GroupedForeignKey. Then you make an inline in the admin for your Conpany with the through model.

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)

class City(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country=models.ForeignKey(Country)

class CCRel(models.Model):
    city= GroupedForeignKey(City, "country")
    company = models.ForeignKey("Company")

class Company(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.ManyToManyField(Country,through="CCRel")
```

And the admin.py:

```
class CInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CCRel
class CAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines=[CInline]
admin.site.register(Company,CAdmin)
```

It should also work with ChainedForeignKey in a similar manner.

You should remove the country field from the Company model as this is redundant.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, just to try it throws me the following error:

companies.Company.countries: (fields.E331) Field specifies a many-to-many relation t
hrough model 'CCRel', which has not been installed.
I followed the steps and do not understand what could be the problem. Hope you can help me. regards

Comment: Have you synced/migrated the database after addint the CCRel model?

Comment: if I deleted the file from the database and have migrated again.

Comment: Do you have a different order of the models than I have posted? In that case try to put the ForeignKey references in quotes: country=models.ForeignKey('Country'). Maybe that helps.

Comment: unfortunately I can not solve .
I've uploaded to a repository , so you can see the full code to see if you can help me solve the error. https://github.com/lsalvay/transportar

Comment: Is there a special reason why you put all of your models into separate model.py files? I think in this case django will not be able to find the CCRel model by referring to "CCRel".You will have to import CCRel and remove the quotes: through=CCRel. Can you try this?

Comment: models are separated , because I like having the modularized applications, but I 've tried importanto the ccREL models and removing quotes -through = " ccREL " but it is not possible. I always get the same error:
empresas.Empresa.paises : ( fields.E331 ) Field specifies a many-to -many relation t
hrough model ' ccREL ' Which Average User installed.

Comment: Can you push up what you did to github. Has the error changed? Can you post more of it?

Comment: As the error was the same , so I turned back all the changes and remains the same.
Thanks for all your help. I hope to find some solution !

Comment: you have a project or a page where implement the solution that you raise me to check it out and see if I can fix my mistake ?

Comment: The code posted above works: just put it into one app.